# How do I assign an object containing an unique_ptr to a vector of its type when a move assignment operator is defined?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, move-semantics, assignment-operator, deleted-functions

The self-contained program section below leads to this error on Visual Studio 2019:

"function "partition_data::operator=(const partition_data &)" (implicitly declared)" is a deleted function.

Based on research around this type of problem I have defined a move assignment operator because of the unique_ptr but I still get the above error. How can I resolve this error in this example?

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct partition_data
{
public:
    partition_data(std::size_t size, double initial_value)
        : data_(new double[size])
        , size_(size)
    {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            data_[i] = initial_value;
    }

    partition_data& operator=(partition_data&& other){
        data_ = (std::move(other.data_));
        size_ = other.size_;
    }

    partition_data(partition_data&& other) noexcept
        : data_(std::move(other.data_))
        , size_(other.size_)
    {
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<double[]> data_;
    std::size_t size_;
};


int main()
{

    partition_data A = partition_data(5, 0.1);
    partition_data B = partition_data(5, 0.2);
    std::vector<partition_data> V(2);
    V[0] = A;  //here occurs the error
    V[1] = B; //here occurs the error
}
```

Comment: "_The self-contained program section_" lacks `#include`s to be self-contained.

Comment: You missed a few - I added them.

Comment: Why do you use `std::unique_ptr<double[]>` instead of a plain `std::vector<double>`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo was just about to make the same edit, but why `<utility>` ? Did I miss something?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 `std::move`

Comment: As for your error, if you look closer you will see that e.g. `V[0] = A` invoke the ***copy*** assignment operator. That's because `A` isn't an rvalue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to move your object:

```
V[0] = std::move(A);
V[1] = std::move(B);
```

or even construct in place

```
std::vector<partition_data> V;
V.reserve(2);
V.emplace_back(5, 0.1);
V.emplace_back(5, 0.2);
```

Comment: Also, `partition_data& operator=(partition_data&& other)` doesn't return `*this` so, UB.

Comment: To add to the above, the compiler will implicitly move some objects (temporaries for example) but since moving is a destructive operation it doesn't move variables on the RHS of assignment statements unless you tell the compiler that is what you want.